# Remove NaN from Pandas and Merge other rows together python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an dataframe contains NaN values and some data. I want to remove NaN values from my dataframe.

How it is:

```
                      data      data1    data2
     0                apple     nan      nan
     1                nan       orange   nan
     2                nan       nan      Mango
```

How I want it to be:

```
                      data     data1   data2
     0                apple    orange  Mango
```

Comment: Please post your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).dropna().values)
```

---

```
    data   data1  data2
0  apple  orange  Mango
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `to_numpy` or `.values` to clear indexing for alignment:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_numpy())
```

OR

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().values)
```

Output:

```
    data   data1  data2
0  apple  orange  Mango
```